# I Dismissed Dogmeat and cant find him anywhere. What do I do?

Tags: fallout-4

Please do not mark this as a duplicate because I could not find any answers on the other pages

I dismissed him and told him to go to sanctuary while on the mission to destroy the institute i did this because I had Nick after i did this I could not find him anywhere and I'm on console so I cant use the moveto Command

Comment: There are plenty of answers.  The fact is, this has already been asked; we don't allow questions asking the same thing.

Comment: not to mention another one was asked about half an hour ago, phrased almost identically.

Comment: Same user (see deleted posts on the other one)

Comment: Build a Bell in your Settlement and ring it, keep ringing it till dogmeat shows up.